# WP8 pivot control - The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pivot

I am currently using multiple textblocks on a pivot control page, but I am unable to change the value of my textblocks. The reason is being "The name 'XXX' does not exist in the current context" even though I have named my textblocks for the value to be written in.
I am able to change the values when using a normal application page but pivot does not allow me to. Is there any way I can get past this?

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="768" Width="480">
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" Loaded="Pivot_Loaded">           

            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Stats">                   
                <Border
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" Background="Black">
                    <Grid Margin="-3,75,-17,-75">

                        <TextBlock
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="10,121,253,422" FontSize="30" Text="Highest Temp : " />
                        <TextBlock
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="10,0,253,551" Text="Current Temp :" FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="10,240,253,311" Text="Lowest Temp : " FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="10,360,253,191" Text="Average Temp : " FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TempAverage"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="222,360,41,191" Text="-" FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TempLowest"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="222,240,41,311" Text="-" FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TempHighest"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="222,121,41,430" Text="-" FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TempCurrent"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="222,0,41,551" Text="-" FontSize="30" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
```

Here is my cs code

```
     if(TempRandom2 > Max) 
       {
         Max = TempRandom2; //Highest Temp = Current Temp

         TempHighest.Text = Max.ToString("0.0"); 
       }

      if(TempRandom2 < Min)
      {
          Min = TempRandom2;
          TempLowest.Text = Min.ToString("0.0"); //Lowest Temp = Current Temp
      }
      AvgTemp[a++ % 100] = TempRandom2;
      if (a > 100)
          TempAverage.Text = AvgTemp.Average().ToString("0.0");
      else
          TempAverage.Text = (AvgTemp.Sum() / a).ToString("0.0");
       }
 }
```

}

Comment: Which line of code throw `The name 'XXX' does not exist in the current context` error?

Comment: TempAverage, Temphighest, TempLowest and TempCurrent.

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to access those TestBlock from another CS file that is not PivotPage1.xaml.cs?  Type `this.` into the CS file to see all its children, I'm sure you are doing it from another file.

Comment: Which part of the CS file should I type this. into? I've just started to take up WP8 programming and I'm not really good at it.